# Undefined variable: info (View: E:\laragon\laragon\www\tutorias2\resources\views\admin\tutores\detalle_tutor.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Al momento de actualizar mi pagina de **detalle_tutor.blade.php** me sale el siguiente error:

```
Undefined variable: info (View: E:\laragon\laragon\www\tutorias2\resources\views\admin\tutores\detalle_tutor.blade.php)
```

Este es el codigo de `detalle_tutor.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layout.dashboard-master')

@section('meta.tab_title', 'Panel de administración | ' . config('app.name'))

@section('content')
     
    <section class="seccion">
        <div class="container">
            <detalle-tutores-form action="{{ url('admin/tutores/detalleTutor/{id}') }}"
                :detalles="{{json_encode($info)}}">
            </detalle-tutores-form>
        </div>
    </section>

@stop
```

Y este es el de `TutoradosController.php`

```
public function detalleTutor(Request $request , $id)
    {
        $info = Maestro::findOrFail($request->id);

        return view('admin/tutores/detalle_tutor',  ['info' => $info]);
    }
```

Comment: despues de `$info = Maestro::findOrFail($request->id)` puedes poner un `dd($info)` y pegar lo que te arroja, de favor

Comment: Si ya agregue el dd($info)     ErrorException {#1462 ▼
  #message: "Undefined variable: info"
  #code: 0
  #file: "E:\laragon\laragon\www\tutorias2\storage\framework\views\0d69865eeb06c42fbb222ddeac44d2681ede47ef.php"
  #line: 8
  #severity: E_NOTICE
}
1